# Add window padding/spacing

Tags: windows, window-manager

Is there an easy way to add window padding/spacing on Ubuntu 18.04

See  the image below for reference/example!

And can you do it without a custom Window Manager like i3?

Thanks!

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

First a general comment. In stacking window managers, your windows open in a default size or in the size the window was previously in. They are placed, depending on the window manger settings, according to a "smart" algorithm or in the center (for Ubuntu 18.04, this depends on the setting of org.gnome.mutter center-new-windows), eventually overlapping existing windows. In this context, automatically providing gaps between adjacent windows makes less sense because windows are not systematically placed adjacent to each other.

That said, such effect could in principle be achieved using a theme where the Window borders are relatively wide and transparent. You may or may not be able to find such theme that suits your taste. Eventually, an existing theme could be edited this way, but it may not be that simple, [for example, see this Reddit discussion](https://www.reddit.com/r/archlinux/comments/6duktu/adding_colored_window_borders_in_gnome/). .css files must be be edited in various places. An added complication is that some window borders may be drawn by the Window manager, others by the client.